# have to add tr -d '\r' after every line in script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run a simple bash shell script (my first..) but it seems that it adds a carriage return after executing every command resulting in a %20D or something added to my commands.. (and therefore failing upon running it)

for example:

```
mkdir /var/MyDir/ | tr -d '\r'
chmod 777 /var/MyDir/ | tr -d '\r'
wget -O /var/MyDir/process-disks.sh 'https://blblabla/disks.sh' | tr -d '\r'
```

if I don't add the tr -d '\r' the commands don't work.. I'm probably missing something very simple.. but what is it.?

Comment: How did you find out that you needed `tr -d 'r'`

Comment: In which way do the programs fail? Is there an error message you can show us?

Comment: yes.. script is created in Visual Studio Code on Windows 10

Comment: More likely, your script has DOS line endings that should be removed. The pipe doesn't accomplish anything, but `tr -d '\r'` becomes `tr -d '\r\r'` which is an otherwise valid command.